# Example of a Lebesgue-integrable function on a non measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The zero function is trivially integrable over any set, or is it? What is a non-trivial function which is Lebesgue-integrable on a non-Lebesgue-measurable set?

Comment: Integral over a non-Lebesgue measurable set is not defined.

Comment: Not even of the zero function?

Comment: The integral of a constant on a set equals the value of the constant times the measure of the set.  If the set is non-measurable, there is no integral.  If the constant is zero you could define the integral as zero, but there doesn't seem to be any point.

Comment: Take the Vitali set, which is non Lebesgue-measurable. Is it wrong to say that the integral of the zero function over the Vitali set ist zero?

Comment: You can define Lebesgue integrals prior to defining set measurability.

Comment: And then the integral of a function $f$ on a subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f \cdot \chi_M$, irrespective of whether $M$ is Lebesgue-measurable or not. It works fine for the zero function on the Vitali set.